# What is "Field Based Page Assignment Criteria" in relation to a custom field?

Tags: custom-field, contact, delete, assignment-rules, field-dependencies

I am attempting to delete a custom field from the Contact object and when I do, I get a message saying it cannot be deleted because it is referenced elsewhere on salesforce.com. The section listed is "Field Based Page Assignment Criteria". Clicking on it forces me out of lightning experience and into salesforce classic before finally informing me I don't have permissions to view it even though I am a sys admin. Can anyone give me any clue as to what this is and how I can disentangle this field so it can be deleted?

[image]

Comment: I *think* there is a way to change how a community page looks based on information from a record. Is there any chance this field may have been used in a situation like this? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5 (Is the field on the user object?)

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by gNerb ^:

I think there is a way to change how a community page looks based on information from a record. Is there any chance this field may have been used in a situation like this? [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5) (Is the field on the user object?)